# Getting information about a request using HttpGetActionInterface

Tags: controllers, magento2.4.3, action, http-request

I'm in the process of removing the deprecated Action implementation from my controllers in favor of the ActionInterface implementations.

With the old extension approach of the `Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action` class, we could simply do

`$this->getRequest()->getHeader('Example');`

to get information from the request.
How can I do this with the new Interface approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

httpgetactioninterface does not provide the request interface.

To get Request information you have to inject/use `Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface` which is behave like `$this->getRequest()`

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php 
...
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class ...
{
    protected $request;

    
    public function __construct(
        ...
        RequestInterface $request
    )
    {
        ...
        $this->request = $request;
    }

   
    public function .....
    {
        return $this->request->getParam('key');
    }
}
```